# Python: Looping over and combining values in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration, dictionary-comprehension

I am creating a nested dictionary that describes several cases ('1ql' and '2ql'), each with a different number of variations ('var0', 'var1', ...). I use dict comprehension in the following manner:

```
from numpy import random as rnd

QLS = {
    key: {
        idx: rad
        for idx, rad in enumerate(['var{}'.format(i) for i in range(rnd.randint(1, 4))])
        }
    for key in ['1ql', '2ql']
    }
```

This works great, but I have been struggling with the how to handle the dictionary for saving to file(s). I would like to iterate over each variation of '1ql', and then iterate simultaneously over each iteration of '2ql'. This can easily be accomplished like this:

```
for key1, val1 in QLS['1ql'].items():
    for key2, val2 in QLS['2ql'].items():
        print('1ql: {}, 2ql: {}'.format(val1, val2))
```

which, for 2 variations of '1ql' and 3 variation '2ql', produces 6 total permutations:

```
1ql: var0, 2ql: var0
1ql: var0, 2ql: var1
1ql: var0, 2ql: var2
1ql: var1, 2ql: var0
1ql: var1, 2ql: var1
1ql: var1, 2ql: var2
```

However, I would like to get this automatically for any number of cases, for any number of variations per case, without having to specify these by hand. I have tried different iteration schemes and even by inverting the inner and outer keys, but to no avail.

I would really like the to learn the most pythonic way to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: that bunch of code using `enumerate` to build the value for `key` can be written simply as `{i: 'var{}'.format(i) for i in range(rnd.randint(1, 4))}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, transform the data to remove the parts we don't need:

```
x = [[(case, var) for var in QLS[case].values()] for case in QLS.keys()]
```

Now `x` is something like:

```
[[('1ql', 'var0'), ('1ql', 'var1'), ('1ql', 'var2')],
 [('2ql', 'var0'), ('2ql', 'var1'), ('2ql', 'var2')]]
```

Finally, use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the result:

```
list(itertools.product(*x))
```

Probably in your real code you'll iterate over the results and use `print()` on each one to get the format you need, but wrapping with `list()` as above gives you an idea:

```
[(('1ql', 'var0'), ('2ql', 'var0')),
 (('1ql', 'var0'), ('2ql', 'var1')),
 (('1ql', 'var0'), ('2ql', 'var2')),
 (('1ql', 'var1'), ('2ql', 'var0')),
 (('1ql', 'var1'), ('2ql', 'var1')),
 (('1ql', 'var1'), ('2ql', 'var2')),
 (('1ql', 'var2'), ('2ql', 'var0')),
 (('1ql', 'var2'), ('2ql', 'var1')),
 (('1ql', 'var2'), ('2ql', 'var2'))]
```